# Low resolution in CentOS

Tags: centos, xorg

It worked perfectly but after I switched to a different LCD monitor, resolution from 1920x1200 to 1920x1080. It only can work on 1280x1024, there is no higher resolution available in resolution list.

I tried system-config-display, it seems system could recognize the new monitor but it doesn't list the best resolution (1920x1080), instead it listed 1920x1200.

What next step I should do? There is no ERROR in Xorg.0.log, only a few warnings:

```
[andych@milerecord]/var/log$ grep WW Xorg.0.log
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(WW) VESA(0): Failed to set up write-combining range (0xd3fe0000,0x10000)
(WW) VESA(0): Failed to set up write-combining range (0xd3fc0000,0x30000)
(WW) VESA(0): Failed to set up write-combining range (0xd3f80000,0x70000)
(WW) VESA(0): Failed to set up write-combining range (0xd3f00000,0xf0000)
(WW) VESA(0): Failed to set up write-combining range (0xd3e00000,0x1f0000)
(WW) VESA(0): Failed to set up write-combining range (0xd3c00000,0x3f0000)
(WW) VESA(0): Failed to set up write-combining range (0xd3800000,0x7f0000)
(WW) VESA(0): Failed to set up write-combining range (0xd3000000,0xff0000)
(WW) VESA(0): Failed to set up write-combining range (0xd2000000,0x1ff0000)
(WW) VESA(0): Failed to set up write-combining range (0xd0000000,0x3ff0000)
(WW) <default pointer>: No Device specified, looking for one...
```

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

You are using the VESA driver, which is probably not what you want. This driver is a 'generic' one which will certainly not work perfectly with your graphics card.

Which graphics card do you have? Please paste the output of `lspci -nn | grep VGA`.

My guess is that CentOS is too old for your modern hardware, so CentOS drivers don't have support for your hardware. I suggest you to try the Live-CD of some modern distribution (Debian Testing, Ubuntu 12.04, Fedora 17) and see if it works fine.

Or maybe your graphics card is *way* too old for CentOS? Could be another possibility..